# How Rendering animation All scene

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to rendering all scene at once

so i'm using this python script code but it won't work

```
import bpy

for s in bpy.data.scene:
   bpy.context.window.scene = s
   bpy.ops.render.render(animation = True)
```

but it's not working when i run this code my blender is just freezing

please help me

Comment: Should work, you just have to wait until the rendering is done. That blender "freezes" is expected when calling the render operator... I'd suggest create a minimal blend file (eg. cube and sphere in different scenes) and test against (monitor your output folder). BTW: Please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The code probably is working as expected, but it’s doing something else you didn’t know it was doing: when blender runs Python code, the UI stops. This usually isn’t a problem since most code finishes within a few seconds, but in the case of this code, render times are being waited on. So until all the scenes finish rendering, the UI would be frozen. I agree with the commentor that suggested you run the code in a minimal blend file with just simple cubes and short frame ranges in each scene to test this diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks your right.

Comment: Please consider to accept the answer in case it is "right", thanks. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers @user117474

Comment: Your welcome! :-)

Comment: Phooey, we both wrote “your” instead of “you’re.”